# Postfix can't receive and send emails

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I installed a fresh ubuntu 18.04 LTS and followed this tutorial:

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-ubuntu-18.04-with-apache-php-myqsl-pureftpd-bind-postfix-doveot-and-ispconfig/

Everything works fine except the mail... I just did everything step by step as the tutorial writes nothing changed or added.

When I login to one of my mail and want to send an email the loading icon is keep spinning...

Here is the /var/log/mail.log:

```
Nov 6 03:12:12 s1 dovecot: imap(support@xyz.com): Logged out in=44 out=592
Nov 6 03:12:25 s1 dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=2940 uid=0 code=kill)
Nov 6 03:12:25 s1 dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.33.2 (d6601f4ec) starting up for imap, pop3, lmtp (core dumps disabled)
Nov 6 03:12:46 s1 postfix/proxymap[2960]: fatal: bad string length 0 < 1: \/etc\/postfix/mysql-verify_recipients.cf_dbname =
Nov 6 03:12:47 s1 postfix/smtpd[1679]: warning: private/proxymap socket: service dict_proxy_open: Success
Nov 6 03:12:47 s1 postfix/master[799]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/proxymap pid 2960 exit status 1
Nov 6 03:12:47 s1 postfix/master[799]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/proxymap: bad command startup -- throttling
Nov 6 03:12:55 s1 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@xyz.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=2971, secured, session=<gwQmwGazCtl/AAAB>
Nov 6 03:12:55 s1 dovecot: imap(support@xyz.com): Logged out in=44 out=592
```

I checked the "mysql-verify_recipients.cf" file and the dbname is filled not empty.

Comment: Show postfix config files.

Comment: Which ones? main.cf, mysql-verify_recipients.cf? or all of them?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This seems to stem from this issue:
https://git.ispconfig.org/ispconfig/ispconfig3/-/issues/5681

What I did was:

```
sudo chmod 777 mysql-verify_recipients.cf
```

I know, I know.

And replaced the /\ in /etc/postfix/main.cf at:

```
check_recipient_access proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-verify_recipients
```

Now, postfix starts and doesn't complain anymore. (My mail still isnt working since I seem to have a certificate issue, but this might help you :))